# How to navigate b/w three views using IBAction button method and round rectangle button in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, xcode4.2

Opening Xcode 4.2, I chose a empty application template. All im trying to do is make three views, which can be navigated through the help of one button inserted [Round Rectangle Button].

I have made 3 Views with three buttons within them which are 
1)Next
2)Next
3)Root

I am relatively new to Xcode. I have imported all the Views into the app delegates. I know i have done everything right. But I think my code for button is wrong.

I inserted a round rectangular button through the object library.

I went in FirstViewController.h, put in -(IBAction)nextbuttonclicked;
I then go in FirstViewController.m, go down, -(IBAction)nextbuttonclicked {

SecondViewController *SVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

[self.window removeFromSuperview];

AppDelegate *appD = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[appD.window addSubview:SVC.view];

}
The error i get is: Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" while

"return UIApplicationMain (argc, argv, nil) NSStringFromClass ([[AppDelegate class]));"

is highlighted hence the thread is coming from here 
Someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Study navigation controller - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

and use navigation controller's **Push** and **Pop** properties for navigations.